# PROBLEMA CON FUNCIONES REGEX

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Tengo un problema con dos expresiones regulares.

La primera necesito que solo me permita ingresar de esta manera.. A-9878 (cualquiera letra de la a-z y cuatro digitos en numero).. La probe en https://regexr.com/ y me indica que esta bien, pero en mi sistema no funciona..

```
 /^([A-Z]-)?[0-9]{4}$/;
```

// Implementacion

```
codigo = document.getElementById("codigo").value;

var a = /^([A-Z]-)?[0-9]{4}$/;

if(!a.test(codigo)){

Swal.fire({
    icon: 'error',
  title: 'No valido',
    });
    return false;
```

La segunda solo necesito que me permita ingresar letras con espacios, si es solo espacio no, y un minimo y  maximo de caracteres alfabéticos. Esta me funciona, pero me deja ingresar una sola letra y no esta siguiendo con el rango de longitud minima y maxima

```
/^([a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ]{1,})( ?)([a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ]{1,})( ?)([a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ]{1,}){3,12}$/;
```

Comment: ¿La primer RegEx tiene forzar una letra, guión y 4 números?

Comment: Si, solo eso. Sin espacios. La probe en regexr.com y me dice que esta bien, pero al implementarlo en mi sistema no funciona

Comment: Cuando decís, no funciona, ¿a que te referís? ¿que es lo que estas probando y no funciona?

Comment: La segunda RegEx ¿el rango es de la cadena completa? ¿cuál es el mínimo y el máximo?

Comment: Que permita ingresar, como por ejemplo: hola como estas.. La longitud minina seria 3 y el maximo 100

Comment: Agregue el ejemplo de como estoy implementando la primera, no corre la primera expresion en mi sistema, solo me deja agregar numeros

Comment: El rango de la segunda, asi es, de toda la cadena completa, minimo 3  maximo 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Primer RegEx:

El problema con la primer RegEx se debe a que esta indicando que la letra y el guión son opcionales al meterlos en `(expresion)?`.

Una solución es:

```
/^[A-Z]-[0-9]{4}$/
```

**Demo:**

```js
function test() {
  let codigo = document.getElementById("codigo").value;
  let regEx = /^[A-Z]-[0-9]{4}$/;
  console.log(codigo, regEx.test(codigo));
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="codigo" value="A-1234" oninput="test()" />
```

---

#### Segunda RegEx:

Para validar que la cadena tenga:

- Letras con espacios, pero no solo espacios:

  ```
  [a-zÀ-ÿ]+( [a-zÀ-ÿ]+)*
  ```
- Y que tenga mínimo 3 y máximo 100 caracteres

  ```
  (?=^.{3,100}$) // Usamos "look-ahead" para validar primero solo la longitud
  ```

Lo que se traduce a:

```
/^(?=^.{3,10}$)([a-zÀ-ÿ]+( [a-zÀ-ÿ]+)*)$/i
```

**Demo:**

```js
function test() {
  let texto = document.getElementById("texto").value;
  let regEx = /^(?=^.{3,100}$)([a-zÀ-ÿ]+( [a-zÀ-ÿ]+)*)$/i;
  console.log(texto, regEx.test(texto));
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="texto" oninput="test()" />
```

Comment: El primero esta ok, gracias. Pero el segundo sigue teniendo problemas. No me deja colocar esto: Como estas hoy.. Solo deja ingresar hasta como estas

Comment: @pedroruiz he actualizado mi respuesta. ¿También necesitas permitir signos de puntuación y números?

Comment: No, solo cadenas de texto

Comment: gracias a vos @Marcos

Comment: Te invito a puntear mi pregunta y así me ayudas a crecer en el sitio